# Al hacer una Prueba de una entidad Parcelable genera un NullPointerException en writeToParcel

Tags: android

Tengo una clase entidad Client. Esta solo tiene un atributo name tipo String. La clase implementa la interfaces Parcelable de android.os

Se  implementaron todo los método para su correcto funcionamiento.

Luego tenemos un Test unitario con JUnit 4. La cual solo prueba  convertir la clase al parcel y viceversa. Se coloco en el gradle app la instrucción unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true con el fin de poder hacer uso del framework completo de android para este test.

El problema esta en el momento que pasa por el metodo WriteToParcel se genera un 
java.lang.NullPointerException. desconocer la razón. mucho les agradecería me guiaran en la solución del error.

Endidad Client

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Client implements Parcelable {

    private String name;

    public Client(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected Client(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name); //linea 20
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Client> CREATOR = new Creator<Client>() {
        @Override
        public Client createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Client(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Client[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Client[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Test

```
import android.os.Parcel;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ClientTest {



    @Test
    public void test_Parcel() {

        Client tClient = new Client("prueba");
        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        tClient.writeToParcel(parcel, 0); //Linea 18
        parcel.setDataPosition(0);

        Client createdFromParcel = Client.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
        assertEquals(tClient, createdFromParcel);
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ve.com.teeac.teeac2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha07"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
}
```

Error mostrado

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ve.com.teeac.teeac2.entities.Client.writeToParcel(Client.java:20)
    at ve.com.teeac.teeac2.entities.ClientTest.test_Parcel(ClientTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: En base a esa pregunta puedes ayudarle a saber porque genera un NullPointerException de acuerdo a su pregunta? @RafaelBautistaMartinez

Comment: Correcto. el Parcel.obtain() era null y por ende generaba el error. Pase de test a android test y la prueba resulto correctamente a ser Instrumentada.